# Attempting to update Git on Mac OS X and uninstall of old Git fails

Tags: macos, git, updates

I am trying to update git on my Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion).

I downloaded this new version from [this link](http://git-scm.com/download/mac), double-clicked on the `.dmg` and then dragged `uninstall.sh` into my terminal (following the instructions [there](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-update-latest-version-git-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/)) in order to uninstall the old version and I get:

```
Git doesn't appear to be installed via this installer.  Aborting
```

Note that `git` is currently installed on my computer.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

Why can't I uninstall? How can I update `git`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a mac the easiest way is to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

1. Install brew
2. Follow the instructions (`brew doctor` will tell you to update your `$PATH` with `/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
3. `brew install git`

And stop worrying about manual updates, just run `brew update && brew upgrade` every so often

Why you can't install the existing one:

- Apple has a default git installation that Xcode uses (in presuming you installed Xcode or at least the command line utilities)

Answer (score 0):

### Shorter answer.

No need to uninstall the Xcode `git` you are seeing in Mac OS X. Just add `/usr/local/git/bin` to your `$PATH` by editing `~/.bash_profile` to add an `export PATH` like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

Then close and save that file and get that loaded into your Terminal session like by typing this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And the newly installed `git` will be accessible to you in preference over the Xcode installed `git` you already have.

### Longer answer.

#### Interpreting the error message.

The issue can be understood by looking at the contents of the `uninstall.sh` Bash script that comes with [the official Git installer package for Mac OS X](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) to see exactly what it does. Here is the snippet near the top that throws the error you are seeing:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -r "/usr/local/git" ]; then
  echo "Git doesn't appear to be installed via this installer.  Aborting"
  exit 1
fi
```

Note the line `if [ ! -r "/usr/local/git" ]; then`, the Bash script is checking for the existence of this directory path:

```
/usr/local/git/
```

But when you ran `which git` the path directory path you got was:

```
/usr/bin/
```

That indicates that the official installer installs `git` its items in `/usr/local/git/` and not in core Mac OS X directory of `/usr/bin/`.

Then what is that other version of `git` you already have in place? Let’s check the output of `git --version` for more details:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)
```

You see that `(Apple Git-31.1)`? That indicates it was installed by Apple. And since `git` is not a part of the core Mac OS X setup, the only way this could have been installed was via Xcode and related command line binaries.

So in short you cannot—and should not—attempt to uninstall the Xcode version of `git`. Instead you want to make your Terminal favor the `git` binaries installed in `/usr/local/git/bin/` over the core Mac OS X binaries in `/usr/bin/`. And you can do this by modifying your `$PATH` setting in `~/.bash_profile` like this.

#### Fixing the issue.

First, open up `~/.bash_profile` in a text editor. I prefer to do this directly in the command line using `nano` like this:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Now if no `export $PATH` exists in that `~/.bash_profile`, just add a `$PATH` line like this to the file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

If an `export $PATH` does exist there, do a modification to that value to get `/usr/local/git/bin` to be before the main `$PATH` of the system. Note the `:` delimiter.

Now close and save that file and get that loaded into your Terminal session like by typing this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now if you type in:

```
which git
```

The output should be:

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

Which means that your Terminal `$PATH` will now check in `/usr/local/git/bin/` before it moves on to check other directories in it’s default `$PATH` values for the `git` binary.

So without uninstalling the Xcode version of `git` you can now download and install the official—and updated—`git` binary and use it without dealing with Homebrew or anything else. For example, on my system this is the current output of `git --version` is as follows:

```
git version 2.5.3
```

No `(Apple Git-31.1)` in sight. Just a pure, `git` version number that is up to date and ready to use thanks to this `$PATH` adjustment.

Answer (score -2):

Having `git` installed is simply not enough. Please also remember that `git` will only work if you're `cd`'d into a functional git repo folder. This means that you should see a `./.git` folder (hint: use `ls -la` to see hidden folders) and `git status` should return something similar to the example below:

```
[some_repo]$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/prod'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

but if the folder is not a valid git repo, you'd see something like this:

```
[~]$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```